# pgfplots: How to draw exponential graph with 60° start angle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, graphs, tikz-graphs

I want to draw a simplified Michaelis-Menten kinetic (monod-function) to compare it with a linear function.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14,   /pgf/declare function={f1(\x)=ln(x);}}% <- This is the exponential function which needs to be optimized

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                    ymin        = 0,
                    xmin        = 0,
                    xmax        = 1,
                    ymax        = 0.9,
                    axis x line = bottom,
                    axis y line = left,
                    ]

%           \addplot[no marks, samples=100, draw=blue] {f1(x)};% This is the exponential graph based on the function
            \addplot[no marks, samples=100, draw=black, thick] coordinates{(0,0) (0.2020725942,0.35)};%
            \addplot[no marks, samples=100, draw=black, thick] (0.2020725942,0.35) to [out=60,in=180] (0.8,0.7) to [out=0,in=0] (1,0.7);%
            \draw[draw=black, dashed] (0,0.7) -- node[above] {\(y_{\text{tot}}\)} ++(0.8,0.0);%
            \draw[draw=black, dashed] (0,0.35) -- node[above] {\(\frac{y_{\text{tot}}}{2}\)} ++(0.2020725942,0) -- (0.2020725942,-0.35);%
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

How can I replace the current graph with an exponential graph?

Start point of the exponential graph:

- Start point: x     = 0.2020725942,
              y     = 0.35,
              angle = 60°,
- End point:       y     = ~ 0.7 (of course, wherever the e-function would end)

As soon as I activate the graph with the exponential function, my whole diagram will be distorted. How to implement an exponential graph based on the upper values correctly?

Comment: This looks like a question of math not of tex/tikz : how should I choose `a` and `b` in `f(x) = a*exp(x)+b` such that `f(0.2020725942)=0.35` and `f'(0.2020725942)=tan(pi/3)` ? If this is the case here is not the right place to ask this question.

Comment: @Kpym: I am sorry, the confusion came because of the mixed axis scalings. NOT because of the function...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is via this (note this uses a differnt function than yours). Your `MWE` is not wrong `IMO`. However, due to varying domains, your final axis is getting mixed-up.

Nevertheless, you can obtain your desired solution with a summation of two-exponents.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    scaled ticks=false,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1.2,
    xlabel=x axis label,
    ylabel=y axis label,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0.2:1.2, samples=1000, red, ultra thick,smooth] {(1-e^(-5*x)-exp(-10*x))*0.7};
\addplot[no marks, samples=100, draw=black, thick] coordinates{(0,0) (0.2020725942,0.35)};%
\draw[draw=black, dashed] (0,0.7) -- node[above] {\(y_{\text{tot}}\)} ++(1,0.0);%
\draw[draw=black, dashed] (0,0.35) -- node[above] {\(\frac{y_{\text{tot}}}{2}\)} ++(0.2020725942,0) -- (0.2020725942,-0.35);%
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am confused: Why doesn't this work with `documentclass{standalone}`?

Comment: @Dave in `standalone` please include `amsmath`.

Answer (score 7):

I would not find a function for that. A curve with exact starting angle (60°) and ending angle (180°) is enough here.

And also, why don't you simply use tan function in Ti*k*Z? 0.2020725942 ≈ 0.35 × tan(30°), but certainly if you type `{.35*tan(30)}` it is more accurate than `0.2020725942`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,.9);
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- ({.35*tan(30)},0.35) coordinate (a);
\draw[thick] (a) to[out=60,in=180] (0.8,0.7) -- (1,0.7);
\foreach \i in {0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8} {
    \draw (\i,.01) -- (\i,-.01) node[below] {$\i$};
    \draw (.01,\i) -- (-.01,\i) node[left] {$\i$};
}
\draw (1,.01) -- (1,-.01) node[below] {$1$};
\draw[dashed] (0.8,0.7) -- (0,0.7) node[midway,above] {$y_\mathrm{tot}$};
\draw[dashed] ({.35*tan(30)},0) -- ({.35*tan(30)},0.35);
\draw[dashed] ({.35*tan(30)},0.35) -- (0,0.35) node[midway,above] {$y_\mathrm{tot}/2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dave I think this is more of an apt answer.

Comment: @JouleV: Thanks a lot for your answer! Yes, I have plotted the line as a simple draw with start angle before posting my request. However, the previous line was too uniform - the Michaelis-Menten-kinetic should have a exponential arc instead of a uniform arc. :-( But your idea of posting lengths calculated by angles is just great! Thanks a lot!